# Ruby on Rails: Access hashmapped form elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, hash

I need to access a hashmapped value from a form. Here is what I see I dump the form elements but I am NOT sure how I can access them in controller:

```
{"Cart"=>{"exclude_discount"=>"1",
 "only_one_product"=>"0",
 "include_surcharge"=>"1",
 "include_timesheet_date"=>"1"}}
```

I tried to access them in controller using

```
params[:Cart[only_one_product]]
and params[:Cart[:only_one_product]]
and params[:Cart["only_one_product"]]
```

Everything fails. Any quick help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want `params[:Cart][:exclude_discount]`

Since it is a hash of a hash, you need to first get the element of the outer hash 'params[:Cart]', then get the inner element of that hash, `[:exclude_discount]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
params[:Cart][:only_one_product]
```

is the right way to access it.

Answer (score 1):

```
params["Cart"]["only_one_product"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Long style

```
cart = params[:Cart] # get hash
is_only_one_product = cart[:is_only_one_product] # get hash key-value
```

Short style

```
is_only_one_product = params[:Cart][:is_only_one_product] # get hash key-value
```